# Can SDK license influence an application license?

Tags: licensing, sdk

Let's say SDK is under specific license that is not compatible with some other licenses (like Flex SDK with GPLv2). Can I create an application by using for example Flex SDK, and license its distribution under GPLv2? Can my application be considered a derivative work? What is a relation between SDK license and application license that was build by using that SDK?

Comment: An SDK license *can* stipulate all kinds of things, it could say something like "Any use of this SDK to create a saleable product is strictly prohibited unless 3% of all sales of the product is given directly to the nearest 6' tall person". Or "Any use of this SDK in the creation of a product either for sale or not is prohibited except when A) the product is translated into 3 languages OR B) the product has zombies listed in it's credits." My point here is: You have to read the licenses. If you aren't used to doing that, time to practice, understanding licenses is an important part of our jobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might. Always **read the license**.